# ssh asking for password

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have a Ubuntu server 18.04 accesible, lets say, at example.com. I connect to it from a MacOS via SSH.

From the client I create my keys like this:

```
cd ~/.ssh 
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f mykey -C "mykey"
```

And I send them to the server like this:

```
cat ~/.ssh/mykey.pub | ssh myuser@example.com "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

The server still ask me for the password. As I understand it, the private key should be stored in the client at `.ssh/mykey`, and the public key should be added in the server at `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and that should be everything needed. But this is not the case here…

Any help will be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [`man 1 ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#i) says:

> `-i identity_file`
>   Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read. The default is `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file. It is possible to have multiple `-i` options (and multiple identities specified in configuration files). […]

The manual doesn't mention `~/.ssh/mykey` as default. Your key will not be used unless you specify it with `-i` or in the configuration file. Or rename the key to `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Comment: Key can also be specified in the client's local [ssh config](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#Host) file [`~/.ssh/config`] as `mykey` under a `Host` entry's `IdentityFile`.  A host entry consists of `Host` with the following four config options: `Hostname`, `Port`, `User`, `IdentityFile` _(i.e. `%d/.ssh/mykey`)_.

Comment: Hi, thanks! So only default names will work, interesting… I will dig on that!

Comment: @Nikita So even with specifying `-i` you're still being requested to provide a passphrase?  Is the key's permissions 600 _(as you only set directory permissions in your command)_? Have you reviewed the server's config to ensure `PubkeyAuthentication = yes`?

Comment: Server conf is correct, as well as folder/files persmisions. Just tested with default name and it works as expected: no passphrase anymore.

Comment: @Nikita Custom names can work, you simply need to either specify them in the `ssh` command with `-i` or specify them in your client config (`~/.ssh/config`) under a `Host` entry ([example](https://pastebin.com/A15NYKDy)).  Host in example is `ESX`, so the ssh command would be `ssh -f -N ESX`